# What is this old biplane?

Tags: aviation-history, aircraft-identification, biplane

Can anyone identify this aeroplane?

Location is Cordoba, Argentina.

[image]

Comment: This is a tricky one. If you could say what the source is if possible that might help. (Cordoba might be Spain, or might be Argentina, for instance.)

Comment: Hi and welcome back! Please take a couple of minutes to take the [tour] and read through the [help] so you can learn how to make the most of the various SE sites! Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a sopwith pup

Answer (score 8):

The aircraft is one of many (5 or 6) **SAML-Aviatik** type "S" and type "A" Italians that flew in Argentina in the '20s. All were for civilian use. Most had Colombo or FIAT engines in line, but the one in the photo (type "A") was the only with a rotary engine (Le Rhone?) that flew in Argentina. It belonged to the Italian pilot Renato Balleri, who together with the American Henry Johnson made public shows of flights, acrobatics, parachute jumping and flight baptisms throughout the country.
Henry Johnson died in an accident one of those events, in the city of Quilmes, in 1934.

The images are of this same plane in the province of San Luis.

[image: San Luis]

[image: San Luis]

[image: San Luis]

Here an Italian SAML-Aviatik A.2...

[image]

Comment: Interesting story, and the wing shows good agreement with the photo in the question. But the engine cowling looks quite different and also the very pronounced step on the fuselage side is missing in the original picture. The engine in question clearly is a rotary one, so again one indication for the SAML-Aviatik. But questions remain.

Comment: The A.2 looks like a good match, the rudder in particular.

Answer (score 2):

Similitudes with the Sommer Arrow from 1914 (the swept upper wing and upper wing root). Wing tips and rudder don't really match, but home made modifications could have been made.

[image]

Source: [flyingmachines.ru](http://flyingmachines.ru/Site2/Crafts/Craft28855.htm)

Comment: Really close! The engine looks slightly different to me too. The wheels are plain on this plane but could have been changed.

Comment: @PartyArk  About the rudder:  No, I think it is triangular rudder with a rounded top and a hinge to connect it to the triangular/curved tail.  It certainly isn't round

Answer (score 0):

Looks a lot like an Anatra D-Series. Note the scalloped trailing edge and the chunky wing struts. These were Russian built aircraft used for reconnaissance during WWI.[image]

Comment: uhm, but in OP's photo there is no cutout for the pilot in the trailing edge of the upper wing. also, the engine shape looks different.

Comment: The landng gear looks further forward than the OP's aircraft

Comment: See the face....not the same

Answer (score 0):

It Looks like avro 504K,see this picture
[image: avro]
[image: avro 504K]

Comment: Note that in the upper photo in your answer the top wing appears to have dihedral, although without more information we could not rule out forward sweep which would create the same appearance from that camera angle.  Note that the upper wing of the biplane in the question appears to have anhedral, which is almost certainly due actually entirely or mainly to the fact that the wing is swept aft, which creates the same appearance from that camera angle.  That's a pretty fundamental difference in geometry-- they cannot be the same type of plane.

Comment: Also consider fore-and-aft spacing of wing stuts which is very small in Avro 504, fin/ rudder shape, strong positive stagger in Avro 504 and little to none in airplane in question, and more.  Also note that the wing struts on the 504 are raked forward relative to the fuselage-connected struts ("cabane" struts).

Comment: See also the triangular geometry of some the "cabane" struts in the question photo.

Comment: Bravo  for this attentive look!